# Launch new program using exec in new terminal

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

I've got a program called ***pgm1*** which create a new process using **fork**.

Then in this process, I launch a new program (***pgm2***) using the following command:
**execv( exec_path_name, argv )**.

But the thing is that with this method I've got both output in the same terminal.
I've been searching for a while ans the only solution i found was this one:

- Open a new terminal with a system call
- Attach my pgm2 to the new terminal using this soft http://blog.nelhage.com/2011/01/reptyr-attach-a-running-process-to-a-new-terminal/comment-page-1/#comment-27264

So my question is really simple, is there a more simple way to do that ?

Thanks in advance !

PS: Distro - Ubuntu 11.10 32bit

Comment: Do you actually want to start a new terminal?

Comment: Yes sure that's what i want, one terminal per program.

Comment: How about `$bash -c prg1`? Exec it.

Comment: I think that this is not adapted to my code, cause i do really need to  launch my program using execv for few reasons.

Comment: What is your *pgm2* doing? Why can't you `popen` it or use several `pipe`-s? Why do you really need another terminal?

Comment: Well i really need two different terminal because both programs process a lot of computations, and then output a lot of lines !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two possible solutions:

1. *Do The Right Thing(TM) and send your output to a file:* Each process can use a different file, providing both clear separation of the output and better record-keeping. As a bonus, you are also bound to see a performance improvement - terminal output is computationally expensive, even nowadays...
2. *Execute a terminal emulator with the proper arguments:* Most terminal emulators provide a way to execute a specific program in place of the shell. For example `xterm`:

   ```
   $ xterm top
   ```

   This will launch `top` in an `xterm` instance, without a shell. Quiting `top` also terminates the `xterm` window.

   If your terminal emulator of choice supports this, you can use it simply by modifying the arguments passed to `execv()`. Of course, in this case you will be actually executing the terminal emulator instead of your program, which will *then* call your own process.

   Keep in mind that, depending on the terminal emulator, any open file descriptors may not be passed correctly to your program - the terminal will *at least* mangle the standard file descriptors.

Comment: The first solution seems to be the right thing to do, and the arguments you give convinced me to do that. But how do I display those file into different terminal ? With a system call: tail -f ... ?

Comment: @Atha: You can always use the second solution to launch windows with `less` or `tail -f` if you feel that it's necessary...